# Email update in Firebase Authentication - Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I want the user to be able to update their email address from within the app. I wrote the following code to update email in Firebase Authentication.

```
val user = firebaseUser.currentUser!!
val credential = EmailAuthProvider
    .getCredential(currentEmail, currentPassword)

user.reauthenticate(credential)
    .addOnCompleteListener {
        firebaseUser.currentUser?.updateEmail(newEmail)
            ?.addOnCompleteListener { updateEmailResult ->
                if (updateEmailResult.isSuccessful) {
                    val userRef = firestore.collection("users").document(userId)
                    userRef
                        .update("email", newEmail)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            onSuccess()
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                            onError(e)
                        }
                } else {
                    val exception = updateEmailResult.exception
                }
            }
```

However, when I debug if (exception != null) works.
The following message is returned:

> The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section. [ Please verify the new email before changing email.]

Edit: I'm adding screenshots of the
[debug_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqmFr.png) -
[debug_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU8Nw.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to reauthenticate the user because the option to authenticate the user with email and password is not enabled. To achieve this, you have to open the Firebase Console, go to the *Authentication* section in your project, and inside the *Sign-in method* please enable Email/Password provider. In the end, it should look like this:

[image]

As the message says, it is also recommended to to verify the new email before changing the email.

Comment: I did this step but the result same

Comment: Are you sure you're enabling inside the right Firebase project?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I even completed this step before I started coding.

Comment: If you sign the user out and you try to sign in again, are you getting the same error?

Comment: I tried to log out and log in again. I added a new user and tried. I tried verifying the email. if (exception != null) works in all cases. :(

Comment: So if you get that exception all the time, no matter if you authenticate, or reauthenticate, then indeed you did **not** enable the option to authenticate the user with email and password. Can you please edit your question and add a print screen from the Firebase Console, as I did in my answer?

Comment: I only get this error only after calling updateEmail. Authentication and authentication are working fine.

Comment: How did you get that error message since the block inside `if (exception != null)` is empty? Can you show us the entire code?

Comment: I put a breakpoint to this line, and debugged, and copy-pasted the exception message here. 
**val exception = updateEmailResult.exception**
null check is for error handling purposes later.

Comment: Have you tried to use `updateEmailResult.exception.message`? What is the result?

Comment: I added the screenshots to the question.

Comment: It's very weird. In this case, I recommend you write and send the problem to the Firebase team. If you do that, please inform us regarding their response.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function instead

```
user.verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(newEmail)
```

of `updateEmail` as `updateEmail` function is deprecated in the newer versions of Firebase.

NOTE: Firebase sends a email link that you need to click new email to change it.